# Electron webview canceled requests

Tags: webview, electron

I'm currently working on an Electron (1.0.1) project where I'm heavily dependent of webviews. Everything works so far except when I try to access `https://twitter.com` or `https://tweetdeck.twitter.com`.

Whenever I try to login (on both sites) the request to `https://twitter.com/sessions` gets canceled and I'm not logged in.

However, if I take a look at the stored cookies I can see a newly generated access token – so when I refresh the site I'm logged in.

Twitter is the only site where I can experience this behaviour and I just can't figure out whats going on here.

The webview initialization is very simple:

```
<webview src="https://tweetdeck.twitter.com" partition="persist:tweetdeck"></webview>
```

[image: dev tools network (take a look at the last request)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't fixed yet but this is a known issue and the Electron folks are already working on it. If you like to follow the issue: [Issue: #3471 Twitter authentifcation form POST REDIRECT](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3471)